# dnsmasq and cname records

Tags: dns, bind, cname, dnsmasq

Need add corretly CNAME record to dnsmasq.
In sample from FAQ can make cname records in config

```
cname=blizzard.cache.lancache.net,cdn.blizzard.com
```

This format return A record for original domain name.

```
# nslookup cdn.blizzard.com
Server:     185.123.187.8
Address:    185.123.187.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   cdn.blizzard.com
Address: 137.221.64.2
Name:   cdn.blizzard.com
Address: 137.221.64.5
```

It`s not correctly for my task. Need return CNAME record. (this answer maked on bind as sample)

```
# nslookup cdn.blizzard.com
Server:     185.123.187.8
Address:    185.123.187.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
cdn.blizzard.com    canonical name = blizzard.cache.lancache.net.
Name:   blizzard.cache.lancache.net
Address: 172.16.0.200
```

This correctly answer. There we can see request to "cdn.blizzard.com", cname record for this domain "blizzard.cache.lancache.net" and ip for cname "172.16.0.200". How make so answer via dnsmasq?

Answer (score 1):

please try:
cname=cdn.blizzard.com,blizzard.cache.lancache.net